# Does NovaCode.DocX contain any textbox controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, novacode-docx

I am trying to create a single page website using c# MVC 4 that has input fields and when the button is clicked it will create a word document. I am using DocX and can at least make a word document with some text right now. I wanted to know if there is anyway I can create a textbox, using DocX. If not, what are my options?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if you can create a `textbox` within a word document using DocX? or if DocX can create a `textbox` within your web page? The answer to both is no. If you are trying to create a `textbox` within a word document you can create a table and insert text within that table. If you are creating a `textbox` on your web page, you don't need DocX to create it.

Novacode-DocX is useful for manipulating template based word document.